# set the base object of derived object?

Tags: c++, inheritance, replace, base-class, object-slicing

This is a basic concept question. If I have a class that Derived that inherits from Base, and I instantiate a new Derived object, can I set it's Base object to a specific Base object of my choosing so that all calls base class methods are redirected to this particular base object?

something like this:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    string name;
public:
    Base(string n) { name = n}
    void doSomething(){cout << name << "\n";}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
     Derived(string n) : Base(n) {}

int main()
{
    Derived* d = new Derived("original base"); //create a derived
    d->doSomething(); // prints "original base"
    Base* rB = new Base("replacement base"); // create a new base object
    ((Base*) d) = rB; // replace the base object of d with a new one (pretend code)
    d->doSomething(); // prints "replacement base"

    return 0;
}
```

I'm sure I made all sorts of errors in that simple code, because my skill level is low, but just for the idea.

Is this possible in C++? We can slice the derived information off of an object, so can we separate and replace the components in a chain of inheritance?

Why would I want to do this?

Consider the mixin lilies: (again, forgive syntax errors)

```
template <class T> class MyMixin : public T
{
public:
    MyMixin(T desiredBaseObject)
    { 
        // do something to set the desired base 
        // object of this class to desiredBaseObject.
    }
};

RandomClass1 dog(int i = 0);  
RandomClass2 cat(double i = 0.0);
MyMixin< RandomClass1 > mixin1(dog);
MyMixin< RandomClass2 > mixin2(cat);
```

In this case, if we could set the base object of the mixin to any desired object, we could use constructors with any parameter list in our mixin without the mixin needing to know anything about it. Also, the mixin could be used like a decorator without the need for a common interface amongst decorators.

Thanks for the answers. Since we can slice off the derived part of an object, it seems like the base and derived information lives separately. Could someone comment on this? Could we access some internal table, like the vtables I hear so much about (I don't know anything about this type of stuff, so maybe this is not applicable), and accomplish this?

@Benoît

Could you explain why only 1 and 4 work, but 2 and 3 do not?
    class Base
    {
    protected:
        std::string name;
    public:
        Base(std::string n)
        {
            name = n;
        }

```
    virtual void doSomething()
    {
        cout << name << "\n";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    int x;
    Derived(std::string n) : Base(n)
    {
        x = 5;
    }

    void printX()
    {
        cout << "x = " << x << "\n";
        x++;
    }
};


Derived* d1 = new Derived("original 1");
d1->doSomething();
d1->printX();
Base* rb1 = new Base("new 1");
*static_cast<Base*>(d1) = *rb1;
d1->doSomething();
d1->printX();
cout << "\n\n";

Derived d2 = Derived("original 2");
d2.doSomething();
d2.printX();
Base b2 = Base("new 2");
static_cast<Base>(d2) = b2;
d2.doSomething();
d2.printX();
cout << "\n\n";

Derived d3("original 3");
d3.doSomething();
d3.printX();
Base b3("new 3");
static_cast<Base>(d3) = b3;
d3.doSomething();
d3.printX();
cout << "\n\n";

Derived d4("original 4");
d4.doSomething();
d4.printX();
Base b4("new 4");
*static_cast<Base*>(&d4) = *&b4;
d4.doSomething();
d4.printX();
cout << "\n\n";
```

this will print:

original 1
x = 5
new 1
x = 6

original 2
x = 5
original 2
x = 6

original 3
x = 5
original 3
x = 6

original 4
x = 5
new 4
x = 6

Why does this only work with when using a pointer?

Comment: Just to be clear, when people say you can't do this, they mean the language says you can't, not the compiler won't let you.  There's probably a way of twisting casts such that it compiles, and maybe even seems to work, but the results are formally undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not questioning why you want to do this, but it's perfectly safe do it unless your inheritance breaks the ISA relationship (eg Derived is a restricted subset of Base, eg a Square is not a Rectangle since it is possible to resize only one dimension of a Rectangle but impossible to do so with a Square).

```
*static_cast<Base*>(d) = *rB;
```

(works also with references)

or you can write a little function (you will find lots of functions doing this):

```
template<typename T>
T& assign(T& to, const T& from)
{
  return to = from;
}

assign<Base>(*d, *rB);
```

and anyway, you do this every time you overload/redefine operator=

```
Derived& operator=(const Derived& other)
{
  // prettier than the cast notation
  Base::operator=(other);

  // do something specific to Derived;
  this->name += " (assigned)";

  return *this;
}
```

Comment: also, why would this not work for a square which inherited from rectangle? What is the difference? Won't the base class methods and values still be replaced? Could you explain some specific cases in which this wouldn't work?

Comment: The Square/Rectangle example is a case where it works technically but is not OK semantically.

Comment: About your edit: static_cast<Base>(d3) = b3; creates a temporary Base, initialized from d3 (that's a construction cast), that's why d3 is not modified. There, it works only with pointer or reference because you then really work on d3. Alternatively, you could write an ugly d3.Base::operator=(b3). Or use a little function like the assign<> i showed you.

Answer (score 3):

No. If you need to do this, you should use composition, not inheritance.

(I'm answering the more general question -- in your specific case where you just want to change the string you can just change `name` from within the derived class)

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance = `IS A` relation.

Composition = `HAS A` relation.

You're describing a class that has an object of type **A** where you can set its instance.
So you need to use composition - Make a class that hold a member of type **A**

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance is a property of **types**, not of **objects**. The *type* "Derived" inherits from the *type* "Base". You can make *objects* of type "Derived" (`Derived x;`), and you can also make objects of type "Base" (`Base y`, unless that's forbidden), but each of those objects are complete, fully-fledged objects with no "replaceable parts".

The point of type inheritance is that you may treat an object of type "Derived" *as if* it was an object of type "Base" (as long as you refer to it by reference or pointer), that is, if you have a function `void foo(Base & b);`, then you may call `foo(x)`. But `foo` can only access those parts of `x` which are inherited from "Base"!

Answer (score 1):

You could combine inheritance & composition:

```
class A {
    string name;
public: A(const char* s) : name(string(s)) {}
        virtual void m() { cout << name << endl; }
};

class B : A {
public:
    B(const char* s) : A(s), a(0) {}
    void m() { if (a) a->m(); else A::m(); }
    A* a;
};

int main() {
    B b("b");
    b.m(); // prints b
    b.a = new A("a");
    b.m(); // prints a
}
```

Comment: this is true and cool, but it requires that B override the methods of A.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that.

You have (at least) a couple of options:

- Create a new `Derived` object, parameterised by a mixture of parameters from the two objects you wish to combine.
- Create some setter methods in the `Base` class, that allow you to change its parameters/state later in its lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Why would you want to do this?  If two Deriveds are supposed to have the exact same Base, such that modifications through one Derived show up in the other, you need to have some sort of pointer to Base in each derived, making this composition, not inheritance.

If you want to change the data in the Derived's Base, write a function to do that, a little like a copy assignment operator for Base.

Alternately, you could make a new constructor for Derived that would take a Base and a Derived, and take Base information from the Base and Derived information from the Derived.