# Can a specific base class object be set as the base object of an inherited class/object in python?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have a class A and a class B derived from A.

After creating an instance of class A with many operations performed, I now want to serialize that specific object. Let's call that object A_instance.

**When initializing class B, how can I tell B that it's base object should be A_instance?**

Within B's **init** i want to decide whether it should normally execute `super().__init__(...)` or setting the base object directly to A_instance.

Here is a code example which makes my question hopefully clear:

```py
class A():
  def __init__(self, a=1):
    self.a = a
    self.message = "Hello, I'm class A"


myA = A(15)


class B(A):
  def __init__(self, b=2, my_base=None):
    if my_base:
      # what should i code here? maybe someting like super().super_object = my_base
      pass
    else:
      super(B, self).__init__()

    self.b = b
    self.message = "Hello, I'm class B inherited from A"


#Then the above code should result in something like:
myB = B(my_base=myA)
assert myB.a == myA.a
```

A similar if not even the same question for C++ can be found here:
[set the base object of derived object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431186/set-the-base-object-of-derived-object)

Comment: Python objects don't have base objects. That's not how inheritance works in Python.

Comment: How is a specific instance of a base class called then actually? And how does python inheritance differ from e.g. C++?

Comment: There is no separate base class instance.